# libGDX black screen in 'Android', works fine on 'Desktop'

Tags: java, android, libgdx, emulation

listen - I'm trying to learn the libGDX API because I want to develop a small cross-platform game, mostly for smartphones (Android iOS).

So I started a new project with the libGDX special setup that the developers made, I installed Gradle on my Eclipse and everything went out great, I ran the 'Desktop' version of the small demo, and it worked out perfectly (Linux if that matters), I even did a couple of changes in the code and made a really small game, which worked out fine.

And then, I wanted to follow my main goal, and start developing for Android, so I ran an emulator, created a brand new clean project, and I was told that the app unexpectedly stopped, then I saw that to run opengl2 in Android emulator I have to check the 'gpu host' box, so I did that.

I restarted the emulator, ran my app and all I saw was a black screen, and in the catlog console I was informed with the next line:

**E/EGL_emulation(1191): rcCreateWindowSurface returned 0**

and -

eglCreateWindowSurface(631): error 3x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)

I don't know what to do now, I even tried to run it in a real Android device and I got the same results, how could I fix this problem/error ?

EDIT: here is some source files if you're wondering -

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class FlappyRabbi extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

     @Override
     public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which emulator did you use? Does it support GL 2.0 ? Is there a Exception stacktrace in logcat?

Comment: I tried using real device, and still same error + My emulator supports GL2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - emulator was probably not supporting GL2.0, I used USB debugging with a real Android device, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

How long have you started your project?
Maybe you are still using a version of libgdx where OpenGL ES 1.x was supported in which case you might need to do something like this in your Android project:

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
config.useGL20 = true; // important line 
initialize(new YourGame(), config);
```

Comment: The closest thing I've got is 'config.useGLSurfaceView20API18' and I tried to set it to true, but I get the same thing.. BTW: I started a whole new project yesterday...

Comment: ah damn you are in a newer version :)    sorry i didn't just comment, but unfortunately i don't have enough rep to comment. Anyway I can recommend you going to their IRC channel, it is where most of the libgdx community are and they are usually very helpful